# djnoer gives TypeError: permission_denied() got an unexpected keyword argument 'code' on get request on /users/me/

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

Doing just a get request on auth/users/me/ results in this error which says the above. Couldn't find anything that helps. Can you help me figure out where this error is coming from and how can I fix it. The link to the tutorial I was following is below. Just had setup a new project and installed djoner with jwt. Below is a detailed error message

Djoner link
https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_usage.html

```
Internal Server Error: /auth/users/me/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 415, in initial
    self.check_permissions(request)
  File "/home/prashant/project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 333, in check_permissions
    self.permission_denied(
TypeError: permission_denied() got an unexpected keyword argument 'code'
[28/Oct/2020 17:40:20] "GET /auth/users/me/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16964
```

settings.py

```py
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
]

# JWT Settings
SIMPLE_JWT = {
   'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'channels.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'channels.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'channelsdb',
    }
}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    re_path('^auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('home', views.Home.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK
class Home(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        return Response({'data':'hello thanks for loggin\' in'}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Please add the code to your `views.py`` as well

Comment: @AmirAfianian added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. It has been reported and fixed:

https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/issues/541

Happy coding.